# SAP Fiori Get Launch Pad User Date format

Tags: sapui5

I need to get Launch Pad Logged in user's Date Format from settings.

I followed methods in [link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadUserItem/methods/addAriaLabelledBy)

And it has methods such as

```
getImage():sap.ui.core.URI
getShowPopupIndicator():boolean
getUsername():string
```

This is how I set Date format in Fiori Launch Pad

[image]

And according to ibn's answer, I tried 
`sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().getDatePattern("medium");`

But it returned `undefined`

The thing is when I first set date format using

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().setDatePattern("medium","mm/dd/yyyy");
```

It returns "mm/dd/yyyy"

otherwise, it returns undefined ... 
And API reference says **"Returns the currently set date pattern or undefined if no pattern has been defined."** 
[Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Configuration.FormatSettings/methods/getDatePattern)

How can I get user's date format from settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().getDatePattern("medium");
```

[image: Image of Console after change configuration on SU01]

Comment: it says undefined. I checked even after publish to launch pad

Comment: Here it's work. I tested before post here.
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().getDatePattern("medium");

return "dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: did you check using SAP web IDE or using cloud platform,
I've updated my question

Comment: I can get language and other settings but not date format

Comment: I test direct on my app on console of Chrome DevTools. But looking your image i think my fiori is a older version.

Comment: mine is 2.0 I think.. I also using chrome dev tools

Comment: mine is before 2.0, I dont have configuration for date format on FIORI, but if i change my default configuration on SAPGUI (SU01) it's change the return, I update the post  with an image of Console .

Comment: the thing is when I first set date format using `sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getFormatSettings().setDatePattern("medium","mm/dd/yyyy");`

It returns "mm/dd/yyyy" by using your code.. otherwise it returns undefined ... And API reference says **"Returns the currently set date pattern or undefined if no pattern has been defined."**

Answer (score 1):

For getting the current date format which has been set for the current user in the Fiori use the following syntax:

```
var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance();// also getDateTimeInstance() exist
var oDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Then you can use the `oDate` object for setting date anywhere, for example in a `DatePicker`.

```
oDatePicker.setValue(oDate);
```

Comment: this gives you browser date, not the date inside the app. They can differ based on certain conditions, like plant date can be different then browser date, if I am in different timezone

Comment: It does not give you date! I spoke about date format not date! You can pass any data that you want. But it is important all part of the app show the dates in a same format. Next time before pressing the 'Vote down' read carefully.